# Using html element to in Laravel where clause

Tags: html, laravel

I have a date in html.

It's populated by js

```
jQuery('.calendar-day-update-edit-trigger').click(function(event){
        var targetDate = jQuery(this).attr('data-day');
        jQuery('.updater-date-edit').html(targetDate);
        jQuery('.hidden-date-input-edit').val(targetDate);
      });
```

I click this to open a modal

```
<a href="" id="pop-up" 
          class="calendar-day-action-button calendar-day-update-edit-trigger"
          data-day="{{ $day->date }}"
          data-action="popup"
          data-target="popup-price-updater-{{ $product->id }}-edit">

             @component('admin._components.atrium-icon', ['size'=>14,'name'=>'add'])
             @endcomponent
          <span>Edit {{ $product->name }}</span>
</a>
```

The date displas in html like this

```
<span name="updater-date-edit" class="updater-date-edit" id="updater-date-edit"></span>
```

How do I use this in a where clause in php tags?

Comment: You can't. PHP is done running after the page loads.  If you want JS to affect the way the page looks, you will need to use jquery for whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. Would you like to execute a server code with the date from client side as attributes? You can use jQuery ajax. api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: How. I populate a variable when a trigger the modal, how can i use the date from the variable